# XML Parsing and query on MySQL select query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table where we have more than 2 Billions rows and my search is always based on Index field .

No new thing that need to try is to get the filed of xml string which is stored in a column which is longtext and varchar(4000)
Both of this column stores xml files one is big xml files and another one is small xmls file.

I need to query on the nodes or filed which is inside the xml files .

for example i need to get the statusCode which is present in fist xml file (DS column 6th column) and providerT which is present in second xml file (SY column last column)

Th search will happen always based on CT_ID which is index column and then on DS SY column .

so i am searching for a query something like

select * from AD_TABLE where CT_ID ='6ththeurtyiru' and DS.statusCode='COMPLETED' AND SY.providerT='noOfNRe';

I know my query is wrong but this can work if i have json but do we have any such thing for xml in MySql?

i have done some search but the query looks very very difficult to understand specially parsing query .

Can some one help me with this please .

```
ID,VERSION,AN_TYPE,EN_TYPE,CT_ID,DS,OT_TYPE,DATE_TIME,GP_ID,OT_NAME,OT_ID,UR_NAME,UR_ID,PT_ID,NS,SY

6uyuitygjh82mcrzz,0,SD_CASE,MYCHECK,6ththeurtyiru
,<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><sCPayload><cId>suerywe7r-21cf-4c7e-8071-suerywe7r</cId><statusCode>COMPLETED</statusCode><sngState>INPROGRESS</sngState><noOfNRe>1</noOfNRe><noOfRRR>0</noOfRRR><noOfER>0</noOfER><noOfARR>1</noOfARR><providerT>WATCHLIST</providerT></sCPayload>,CASE,9/16/2020 9:45,bd7c9519-d726-4672-8599-83d21927bec5,,5f53b903-21cf-4c7e-8071-suerywe7r,System User,USER_SYSTEM,,,<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><screenCES><providerT>MYWATCH</providerT><noOfNRe>1</noOfNRe></screenCES>,
```

Comment: which version you are using and MySQL or MariaDB ?

Comment: @BerndBuffen Mysql i can use Even Maria DB also

Comment: i like MariaDB, but its not necessary, only the syntax for virtual field its a litte bit different

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL8.0, you can use [ExtractValue](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/xml-functions.html)

For MariaDB (10.5) the docs are: [ExtractValue](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/extractvalue/)

```
mysql> set @xml='<sCPayload><cId>suerywe7r-21cf-4c7e-8071-suerywe7r</cId><statusCode>COMPLETED</statusCode><sngState>INPROGRESS</sngState><noOfNRe>1</noOfNRe><noOfRRR>0</noOfRRR><noOfER>0</noOfER><noOfARR>1</noOfARR><providerT>WATCHLIST</providerT></sCPayload>';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> select ExtractValue(@xml,'//statusCode');
+-----------------------------------+
| ExtractValue(@xml,'//statusCode') |
+-----------------------------------+
| COMPLETED                         |
+-----------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

Comment: set @xml will be done for full table ?How do we set this for every row ?

Comment: To do it for every row in your table, you have to do something like `select ID,VERSION, ExtractValue(DS,'//statusCode') statusCode,ExtractValue(DS,'//sngState') sngState,ExtractValue(DS,'//providerT') providerT;`

Comment: so this is select but i have to run `set@xml ` first how will i be able to do that ?and above will be for every column but still be for one row ?

Comment: no, `set @xml = ....` wil just create a variable, see: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/set-variable.html

Comment: sorry if i am confused but the value we are setting is just for one row ..I did set this and when i query for other row i get null as result

Answer (score 0):

You can also put the result from extract in a permanent virtual field. so you can build a index or combined index to get a fast result and not a FULL TABLE SCAN.
This field will be automaticly be updated if you change the XML

Add this field to your Table

```
ALTER TABLE yourTable

    ADD COLUMN
    `statusCode` varchar(16) AS (ExtractValue(DS,'//statusCode')) PERSISTENT;
```

Comment: But is this Alter table same as MySql Aurora normal alter because that is very expansive operation. Also if i select first based on Index in that case also Index is required for that filed ? last one statusCode is just for and example can i use this for any of the field ?

Comment: Also i have more than 10o nodes in xml so does this mean i need to create 100 columns persisted one ?